# Team foundation server:error when I click on the solution file in source control explorer

Tags: tfs, solution, team-explorer

Here is the error message that I am getting "The solution contains unloaded project.Any change you make will not affect the unloaded project. It is strongly recommanded that you reload all project before contuning."

What does this mean? How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking on the unloaded project after the solution loads and look for a command to load the project. If there's an error loading the project, that error will likely be more descriptive of why the project isn't loading. It may be because you didn't retrieve a local copy of that project's files.

Comment: I don't know the unloaded project I have a solution that contains my project and to open the project I am click on the solution file in source control explorer.

Comment: Generally I don't open solutions from source control explorer. I retrieve local copies of all the projects in the solution and open it locally because I don't think opening a solution from team explorer directly works if you don't have the projects locally.

Comment: What I do is I have the solution(folder containing all the solution parts) in source control explorer and then I create a branch of it; after creating the branch I create a workspace that maps the branch(it download the project on my computer) to mean that I have the copy of the project locally(solution folder because when I open the solution all the project of the solution are opened too.).

Comment: I think what I should do is to open the solution locally to see if the same error will show up again; I let you know. 

But Do you mean that normally solution or project  that is part of a team project should be opened from it local copy?

Comment: I don't have a very good answer to that; all i can say is that's how I always open solutions and projects - locally.

Comment: I did as you do it worked fine for me but every time it showing up the windows asking to bind the solution.